# Modelling percentage and proportion data with GLM's

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, proportion, percentage

I would like a simple answer, if there is one, to a question I cannot seem to find on here. 
What is the best way to model percentages?

Say I have a glass that is empty and I fill it with liquid until it is full. It starts on 0% full and ends on 100% full.

I want to explore what influences the rate it fills using the percentage as the response.

Say I have two independent variables: liquid type and tap design and I measure the percentage the glass is filled over monitoring intervals.

```
Monitoring interval  Liquid Type  Tap Design Percentage Full
1                    Water        Funnel     15
1                    Water        Sieve      11
1                    Water        Jet        22
1                    Honey        Funnel     4
1                    Honey        Sieve      2
1                    Honey        Jet        7
1                    Oil          Funnel     6
1                    Oil          Sieve      5
1                    Oil          Jet        12
2                    Water        Funnel     39
2                    Water        Sieve      31
2                    Water        Jet        75
2                    Honey        Funnel     24
2                    Honey        Sieve      15
2                    Honey        Jet        36
2                    Oil          Funnel     29
2                    Oil          Sieve      26
2                    Oil          Jet        46
```

I stop monitoring when they all reach 100%.

Note.. I just made that up as an example, so for the purposes of this question please assume I have to use a percentages as my response rather than a more suitable scaled measurement.

How can I see which factors i.e. liquid type or tap design influence the percentage of glass that gets filled?

Should I use a GLM with code similar to this:

```
glm(Percentage Full ~ Liquid Type*Tap Design, family = binomial)
```

How can I convert my percentages into a suitable response to be modelled in this type of GLM?

Or any other suggestions?

*** EDIT ***

Real data to answer this question:

I am looking at wound healing over time and have hit a wall with analysis. My data consist of injury cases which are tracked over time. Injury healing is measured as percentage wound area/perimeter change since initial sighting. Each case varies in the number of days since initial sighting and the total number of sightings, with some only seen twice and some seen 5 times.

DV = `Area Change`

IV = `Days`, `Severity`, `Location`, `Type`

Random effect = `Shark ID`, `Injury`

I want to look at changes over time and be able to statistically explore whether wounds are decreasing in size over time and what factors can influence this. Key points:

My response is a percentage that is dependent on previous records.
How can I combat this?

Here is an example of data:

```
Injury  Shark ID   Name      Date     Days    Severity  Location  Type        Cause      Area Change     Perimeter Change  
1       WS198      Naococco  24.6.15     0    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat                 0                    0
1       WS198      Naococco  8.7.15     14    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        74.6858632           63.6698483  
1       WS198      Naococco  10.7.15    16    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        81.4165492           77.0354486  
1       WS198      Naococco  1.8.15     38    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        81.9152998            89.704627  
1       WS198      Naococco  4.8.15     41    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        86.2165258           89.1497158  
1       WS198      Naococco  18.8.15    55    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        86.1513557           90.3776043  
1       WS198      Naococco  19.9.15    87    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        97.9639636           93.7961375 
1       WS198      Naococco  24.9.15    92    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        96.8353572            91.813769     
1       WS198      Naococco  3.11.15   132    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        99.7190944           98.0207677 
1       WS198      Naococco  10.11.15  139    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        99.8686985           98.8372268  
1       WS198      Naococco  30.11.15  159    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat               100                  100 
2       WS198      Naococco  27.3.16     0    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat                 0                    0  
2       WS198      Naococco  29.3.16     2    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat         28.902414           17.0816156   
2       WS198      Naococco  4.4.16      8    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        47.1829361           45.5672997  
2       WS198      Naococco  30.5.16    64    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        97.4773761           91.7192607 
2       WS198      Naococco  13.9.16   170    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat               100                  100 
3       WS198      Naococco  5.10.17     0    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat                 0                    0 
3       WS198      Naococco  26.10.17   21    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        65.2492641           67.0574269  
3       WS198      Naococco  30.10.17   25    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat        68.9993994           66.1401071 
3       WS198      Naococco  10.12.17   66    Major     Flank     Laceration  Boat               100                  100
```

Please tell me if this does not make sense or if more information is required to clarify my question.

I know I cannot to a standard lmer model as follows because of my response:

```
healing.lmer <- lmer(Area Change ~ Days + Severity*Type*Location + (1 | Shark ID) + (1 |Injury), data = healing)
```

How can I change my response or my model to fit?

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for your suggestion, I have asked the question with my specific data a few times and not had a response which is why I attempted a different approach here. Please see my original question: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386552/time-series-of-wound-healing]